# Microsoft SQL error in string for wrong syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

First time posting on here.

Please can someone help me with this very simple error that I cannot seem to fix.

```
if @DivResult > 0 and @IfMenu = ('A','F')
```

There is a syntax error near the comma

Comment: @IfMenu in ('A','F')

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid tsql syntax: `and @IfMenu = ('A','F')`

The correct would be: `and @IfMenu in ('A','F')`