# How to do many OR matches in SQL against a list?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, syntax-error

How can I resolve the first comma? There is a syntax error.

```
if (@BAAgtNo = '0000ZV') and
   (@ProfileNumber = '902876'***,*** '903673', '903674', '903675', '903676', '903677', '903678', '903679')    -- If the booking agent result is 0 then..
begin
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft SQL error in string for wrong syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206679/microsoft-sql-error-in-string-for-wrong-syntax)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `IN`:

```
if @BAAgtNo = '0000ZV' and
   @ProfileNumber in ('902876', '903673', '903674', '903675', '903676', '903677', '903678', '903679')    -- If the booking agent result is 0 then..
begin
```